# wordpress generate bfi_thumbs in uploads folder how can remove code from wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i had one wordpress site which has install one theme related managment . now there is one folder created uploads/bfi_thumbs .

when we check google page speed score at that time it will give me error **Optimize image** and image path like that **uploads/bfi_thumbs/imagenamehere-somerandom number code.extension**

now i want to remove this folder and optimize image on google page speed how it can possible ?

Comment: Please help me my wordpress site not showing actuall result in Google page speed

Comment: Done !!!!!!! hurry....

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: how did you do that?